# Ajax + Codeigniter

Tags: json, codeigniter, url-amigável

Bom dia....

Acabei de implementar o Codeigniter, porém não consigo utilizar url amigável...

Tento passar parâmetros por Ajax, porém não consigo devido às URLS.

Já retirei o `index.php` do arquivo `config.php` e alterei o `routs.php`

Já inseri o seguinte código no `htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]]
```

Comment: Qual erro que aparace?

Comment: Como está seu Ajax e qual é o erro retornado na requisição?

Comment: erro 404, o mesmo acontece se tento acessar a função diretamente pela url

Comment: $.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "<?php echo base_url('/login/realiza_login'); ?>",
     data: { login: login_front, senha: senha_front }
   })
    });

Comment: Já tentou acessar a url diretamente pelo navagador, para ver ser está funcionando?

Comment: Você configurou a variável $config['base_url'] para a url do seu site?

Answer (score 1):

Pra fazer o servidor funcionar com URL amigável você precisa, além de ativar o módulo mod_rewrite, habilitar também a diretiva AllowOverride ([leia aqui](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/pt-br/mod/core.html#allowoverride)) no diretório de hospedagem.

**Só um conselho:** Tudo o que um htaccess faz, o Apache deve fazer com arquivos de configuração, e passar comandos pelos arquivos de configuração é mais seguro ([o desenvolvedor diz isso](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/pt-br/howto/htaccess.html)). Sabendo disso, talvez seja melhor configurar isso no arquivo geral do servidor mesmo. Assim:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/seu_sistema">
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
AllowOverride All
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

Viu como **AllowOverride All** está definido? É isso.

OBS: com essa configuração, não precisa mais usar os .htaccess.